# Count items in nested field array for if/then in template

Tags: theming

I'm sure I'm missing something very straightforward here:  I want to prevent the thumbnail slider in my image gallery from being rendered if there's only one image for the node. My first thought was, optimistically:

```
  <?php if (count($content['field_media']) > 1): ?>
    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider clearfix">
      <div class="slides">
        <?php print render($content['carousel']); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

I saw why that didn't work when I examined the node structure. In an example case for a node with one image, I have

```
 field_media (Array, 1 element)
    und (Array, 1 element)
        0 (Array, 17 elements)
```

the last one being the actual file element with an fid, etc. The corresponding field for a node with two images is

```
 field_media (Array, 1 element)
    und (Array, 2 elements)
        0 (Array, 17 elements)
        1 (Array, 17 elements)
```

So the array I need to count is nested inside the 'und' array. I know I've used that in other templates, like $field_external_link['und'][0]['url'].  But when I print count($content['field_media']['und']), I get 0.  How do I evaluate the number of elements in that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [field_get_items](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) api function to read values.

```
<?php

$images = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_media');
if (count($images) > 1) {
  // Print Carousel
}
?>
```